# Is it ok to tag a [kotlin] question with [java]?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-question

The following question [DateTimeParseException - could not be parsed at index 15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66231257/datetimeparseexception-could-not-be-parsed-at-index-15) contains Kotlin code.

It is tagged with [kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin) and [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java). Is the Java tag ok here? It seems to concern a problem in the JDK classes.

Comment: Yes and no. If this was about plain Kotlin, yes. When OP [says it's Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66231257/datetimeparseexception-could-not-be-parsed-at-index-15#comment117094362_66231257), arguably, Android takes priority over Java. All three tags can strictly speaking be present, but doesn't make sense in this case.

Comment: Arguably, the [[tag:kotlin]] tag wiki should include that sort of usage information, but [currently includes nothing close](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/kotlin/info).

Answer (score 2):

In this case, yes, because the problematic component was a class provided with the JRE.

In general, no. Because Java and Kotlin are different languages.

I would prefer a way to highlight posts that use java and kotlin tags simultaneously before submitting and asking the author to double check them, because it seems that very often the tags are used incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

From the profile of the answerer it seems as if this question was answered by someone following the Java tag. If we see the tag system as means to get questions to answerers, then I'd say that adding [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) was the right thing to do.

Also as one can use code written in Java in code written in Kotlin it is in general totally fine to tag both languages if both are involved (unless the answer's code is supposed to be in one of the languages, in that case the question should clearly decide).